# Catch long press of volume button in sleep(android)

Tags: android, button, sleep

I need catch long press of volume button when phone is sleeping(screen off) and I know this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
    {
        // to your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

is not helpful(it works only in active intent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm curious about this too.
While this isn't necessarily an answer, I have done some research on Services (to catch the volume press I'm guessing) and BroadcastReceivers (onReceive() would receive an intent for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and probably set a flag for the screen being off).  My thinking is starting the service when the screen turns off and kill it when the screen turns on, but I don't know how to join onKeyLongPress and the service.

The sequence I see happening is this: Screen turns off -> BroadcastReceiver receives this command and starts the service to watch for volume press -> receive volume press and do your logic -> kill the service if the screen turns on.

I found a site that apparently handles screen off/on and has an example for an activity and a service but I can't get something together yet:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

One thing I'm worried about when using a service is battery life and processing time but that will be testing down the road.  I will hopefully be able to mitigate that with killing the service when the screen turns on.  I'll try to keep this entry updated as I make progress.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, I am trying to receive volume up and down events when my phone is in sleep mode, I gone through most of the answers in this forum, no concrete answer that is possible or not. Some of the Android phones, doesn't camera button like HTC. Any help is greatly appreciated... I am looking only for events for the volume buttons when the device is in sleep